# AWS-SNS; How to get valid SubscriptionARN after user confirmation

Tags: amazon-web-services

System: Windows, C#, Visual Studio 2015, AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService

Using AWS-SNS, after creating a topic I add a subscription to the topic as follows;

```
var response = SnsClient.Subscribe(topicArn, "email", email);
var subscriptionArn = response.SubscriptionArn;
```

Initially, my subscription ARN is set to "pending confirmation" - presumably until the user confirms their subscription via email. I would have thought that calling subscribe again with the same email subsequent to confirmation would have returned a vilid ARN, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Not having the subscription ARN prevents me from later unsubscribing an email from a subscription group. I'm sure there is a way to overcome it short of requiring the user to copy / past the email token into my application - but I can't seem to find it.

Thank you in advance.

SteveJ

(PS. I should note that the answer need to be C# specific - just a generic approach to the problem using their SDK or web API is fine.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon SNS [Subscribe documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html) says:

> The following element is returned by the service:
>
> **SubscriptionArn**
>
> The ARN of the subscription, if the service was able to create a subscription immediately (without requiring endpoint owner confirmation).

Therefore, it appears that an Email subscription only receives an ARN **when the subscription has been confirmed**.

You will need to identify the subscription (once subscribed) by calling [`ListSubscriptionsByTopic`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_ListSubscriptionsByTopic.html), looking for the `Endpoint` that matches the desired **email address**. You could then extract the ARN and use it when calling [`Unsubscribe`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Unsubscribe.html).

Comment: Ooh..Hadn't thought of that - thanks, let me give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the solution.